# How to reset View and its object after pushviewcontroller in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, object, uiview, pushviewcontroller

I have a scenario in which I have a home screen through which I am pushing to a new mode, which means a new class and a new view, in my new view I am using this:

```
  [button removeFromSuperview];
```

when I run the app for the first time it works, but when I go back to home and come back to the new mode again the button does not appear. I am new to Xcode and don't know how to handle this problem. please guide me, how can I solve it?

Comment: What? Why are you removing the button? And in which method are you removing the button, and again why? Why are you wondering that the button isn't shown when you remove it? And please show us more relevant code!

Comment: you probably want to release the whole view you are pushing instead of removing its controls. Or if pushing a new mode means you change the way the view is being displayed or which controls are shown, please give us some more code.

Comment: @ dasdom, i just want to reset it state as it runs for the first time, i removed button at the end of game, now i want to play again but there is no button out there guide to reset its state like as first time

Comment: Ok, if you remove the button in, let's say, `viewDidDisappear:` you could add the button in `viewWillAppear:`. Please show us the code which constructs you view. Or are you using stroyboard? Are you using ARC?